# laravel validation rule does not accept first index of array

Tags: php

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request) {
    $rules = [
        'translations'                  => 'required|array',
        'translations.*.language_code'  => 'required|exists:app_languages,code',
        'translations.*.name'           => 'required'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    dd("OK");
}
```

I am using PostMan to test it. Everything is ok for array's second parameter. But it does not accept name 0 index or array.

[image]

When i didn't send first index :

[image]

**UPDATE**

It is Postman's bug. I added same parameter then replace it, it works.

[image]

Comment: array is multi array or single array ?

Comment: array is object array. Multidimensional but second layer is object. translations[*]["language_code"] and translations[*]["name"]

Comment: try  adding `'translations.0.name'           => 'required'`

Comment: @madalinivascu ieda is bad!

Comment: @Mohammad why do you think its a bad idea?

Comment: i am sorry. This is postman's bug. I added same 1 key-value to body with same name. It works. Really interesting. Thank you

Comment: @madalinivascu Because the index may change.

Comment: @Mohammad he said the first item at [0] doesn't work, the rest works

Comment: @madalinivascu Consider [1] or [[0], [2]] Indices are required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Postman's bug. I added same parameter then replace it, it works.

I do not know, why it didn't accept and now it accept lol.

Comment: try removing the indexes do it like `translations[][name]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps you .

```
$rules = [];
if($request->has('translations'))
{
    $translations = $request->input('translations');
    foreach($translations as $key => $value)
    {
        $rules["translations.$key.$value"] = 'required';
    }
}
```